# React style rectangular div as in example

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a div in my react application:

```
  <Col  xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6}>
      {/* contains change email component */}
      <div className="div-two-up">
         <If condition={this.state.showEmailReset}>
             <div className="email-reset-div">
                 <ResetEmail/>
              </div>
           </If>
        </div>
   </Col>
```

And it's css:

```
.email-reset-div{
  border: 2px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

This renders like normal rectangular div with border of 2 px. I want it to look like following only on large screens, otherwise normal rectangular div.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a pseudo-element using pure css, like

```
 .email-reset-div::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent; 
    border-right:20px solid blue; 
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Remember to add `position: relative;` (for e.g.) to the original `div`.

Keep all the values that are 20px the same (or if using Sass/SCSS use a variable)

demo of the css here https://jsfiddle.net/mw2vpgnr/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the diagram in my question wasn't accurate one. I have modified it, could you perhaps point out how to achieve it? I am basically just showing borders without any color inside..Thanks anyway though :)

Comment: Also only on large screens :)

Comment: For 'only on large screens' you can use a media query. So you would wrap the pseudo-element with something like `@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) { ..  }` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp


for the new shape - try changing the values on the borders and you can see how it affects the triangle shape :) (hint, try changing the border-top and border-bottom to get your new shape). the borders are hard to achieve with pure html / css, you would instead want to look at adding a background image to the pseudo-element that fits with the existing div.